# Trying to add data to boxes without the xpath, a tricky situation [SELENIUM & JAVA]

Tags: java, selenium, gridview, datagrid, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on this grid, using SELENIUM & JAVA and chromedriver.

Take a look at this and it's behaviour (it is a .gif):

[image: gif1]

> When i need to add a new row to that grid i have to click on
> "ADD OPTION" and then a new row is inserted

The problem is that i do not understand how to pass a **collection of values**, i want to achieve this:

I want to pass a collection and my program should place them in the grid (2 values each row) without getting the xpath of every single box. I need to make it more efficient.

---

**Example:** i have this collection:

```
["fdfdfddf","989"; "RERE","6655"; "HEHE","554"; "TTER","89"]
```

I want my program to place them in the GRID.

**Desired result:**
[image]

---

The problem is that in my code i do need to know the xpath of each "box" of the grid in order to insert data.

This is my code to add data to the grid:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("add_new_option_button")).click(); //it clicks on "Add Option" button
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"manage-options-panel\"]/table/tbody/tr[40]/td[3]/input")).sendKeys("fdfdfddf");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"manage-options-panel\"]/table/tbody/tr[40]/td[5]/input")).sendKeys("989");
driver.findElement(By.id("add_new_option_button")).click();
```

**How can i fill in the boxes without knowing the xpath of every box?**

**I don't want to click on every box of each row to get the xpath, i need to find another fast solution.**

This is how i get the xpath of every box:

[image]

Comment: This looks the same or very similar to your last 2-3 posts.

Comment: Is this also going to be self-answered answered by using `By.className`?

Comment: Hey @HovercraftFullOfEels not, it is not at all. It is different, the las 2 post were about a problem clicking on a row, it is not the same and i was able to solve it

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i'm not following you, pal

Comment: That's OK. I'll let the site moderators figure it out along with the voting patterns. I'm gone

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i dont understand what you saying. I made 2 questions almost the same because i wanted to find a solution and this one is about a collection

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by using xpath like.

```
Xpath=//*[@type='text']//following::input
```

Here First target a element which is just before your input box then when you add any new box then the xpath will like

```
Xpath=//*[@type='text']//following::input[1]
Xpath=//*[@type='text']//following::input[2]
Xpath=//*[@type='text']//following::input[3]
```

Now you can run a loop or otherway and input value inside the box without taking different xpath

Comment: Thanks for replying, pal. I'm checking this out